# Flask Dash passing a variable generated in a callback to another callback

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

In a callback, a dataframe is created from user inputs. I need to use that dataframe in another function, in order to serve it to the user.
I read that server.route can do this, with Flask SendFile, but I can't access the dataframe since I cannot use global variables.

I have read there is a hidden div method but I don't know how I can access a html div property from inside of python.

'''

```
server = flask.Flask('app')

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
external_stylesheets=external_css,
server=server)

master = pd.read_csv('master_dataframe.csv')

@server.route("/downloadable/")

def download_file():

    df = # The dataframe I need that is in the other function
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    dff.to_excel(buffer)  # write to BytesIO buffer
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        buffer,
        attachment_filename='data.xlsx',
        as_attachment=True,
        cache_timeout=0
    )
@app.callback(
    Output('plot_button','n_clicks_timestamp'),
    [Input('account_selector','value')]
)
def generate_layout(value):
    df = make_something(master, value)
    return html_layout
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

You could output the contents of the dataframe in JSON format to the `children` prop of a `div` with `display='none'`. Then use another callback with the `children` of that `div` as its `Input`, and you'll be able to read the JSON and use that data.

Quick example:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('my-hidden-div','children'),
    [Input('my-input','value')]  # whatever this will be
)
def generate_df_callback(value):
    df = make_df_from_input(value)
    return df


@app.callback(
    Output('my-output', 'value'),  # whatever this will be
    [Input('my-hidden-div', 'children')]
def use_df_callback(df):
    foo = do_something_with_df(df)
    return foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I use this callback after the server.route decorator? Because I need to send the file after the user access “/download/“ url

Comment: I'm not totally sure, because I haven't used the `server.route` decorator much, but I think the answer is "no", because the hidden div would not be on that page. Worth a try, though. If it does not work, you could also look at outputting the JSON to [local storage](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/store), which should be available regardless of route.

Comment: have you been able to find out the answer to that? I am trying to build the same procedure in my application.

Comment: If the local storage option doesn't work, then I'm not sure.